# mod_rewrite prepending subdomain name to query string

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to force a redirect from the `www` subdomain of a website to the `forum` subdomain, while preserving query string. In other words, I expect this:

`http://www.website.com/index.php?key=value`

To turn into:

`http://forum.website.com/index.php?key=value`

So I wrote this *supposedly* simple rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://forum.website.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

This is the *only* rewrite rule I have in my .htaccess.

The sample url above gets rewritten into:

`http://forum.website.com/forum/index.php?key=value`

What is this strange (and, to me, unexpected) behavior? What am I doing wrong / missing?

---

EDIT 1: Added rewrite logs (trimmed useless date info)

```
[www.website.com/sid#7f3580c0a4d8][rid#7f3580d935a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/website/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/website/forum/test -> forum/test
[www.website.com/sid#7f3580c0a4d8][rid#7f3580d935a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/website/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'forum/test'
[www.website.com/sid#7f3580c0a4d8][rid#7f3580d935a0/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/website/] RewriteCond: input='www.website.com' pattern='^www\.website\.com$' => matched
[www.website.com/sid#7f3580c0a4d8][rid#7f3580d935a0/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/website/] rewrite 'forum/test' -> 'http://forum.website.com/forum/test'
[www.website.com/sid#7f3580c0a4d8][rid#7f3580d935a0/initial] (2) [perdir /var/www/website/] explicitly forcing redirect with http://forum.website.com/forum/test
[www.website.com/sid#7f3580c0a4d8][rid#7f3580d935a0/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/website/] escaping http://forum.website.com/forum/test for redirect
[www.website.com/sid#7f3580c0a4d8][rid#7f3580d935a0/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/website/] redirect to http://forum.website.com/forum/test [REDIRECT/301]
[forum.website.com/sid#7f3580c54d70][rid#7f3580d935a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/website/] add path info postfix: /var/www/website/forum/forum -> /var/www/website/forum/forum/test
[forum.website.com/sid#7f3580c54d70][rid#7f3580d935a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/website/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/website/forum/forum/test -> forum/forum/test
[forum.website.com/sid#7f3580c54d70][rid#7f3580d935a0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/website/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'forum/forum/test'
[forum.website.com/sid#7f3580c54d70][rid#7f3580d935a0/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/website/] RewriteCond: input='forum.website.com' pattern='^www\.website\.com$' => not-matched
[forum.website.com/sid#7f3580c54d70][rid#7f3580d935a0/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/website/] pass through /var/www/website/forum/forum
```

---

EDIT 2: This is my website.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/website/forum/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.website.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/website/forum
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName forum.website.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/website/forum
    <Directory />
         AddHandler fcgid-script .php
         FCGIWrapper /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5 .php
         Options ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Your rewrite rule is fine -- I see nothing wrong. 1) Maybe you have rewrite rules in another place (inside `<VirtualHost>` for example). 2) Do you have `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` directives anywhere? 3) Maybe (just maybe) it is done by forum code? I recommend use Firebug for Firefox (Net panel) or any other similar tool and see what is actually happening.

Comment: 4) How much control do you have over your server? Can you edit Apache's  config files (httpd.conf or httpd-vhost.conf)? If yes -- then enable rewrite debugging `RewriteLogLevel 9` and see what is going on. 5) Does www and forum subdomains are pointing to the same folder? Maybe rewrite is done on in htaccess on forum website?

Comment: @LazyOne: yes, they point to the same directory, namely `/var/www/website/forum`. The .htaccess is in `/var/www/website`. I added rewrite logs, thank you for the suggestion! Even though I still don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking your rewrite logs I see that `forum/` is already part of URL. Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com$
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*) http://forum.website.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: @Cicada Has to be something with the way how you declared website in `<VirtualHost>` I guess -- `DocumentRoot` directive most likely. Post it (update your question) if you wish and we can look into it.

Comment: @Cicada TBH I see nothing there that would causing such behaviour. In any case -- .htaccess is located in parent folder (and somehow works), therefore all rules should be relative to that folder: `/forum/` is a subfolder so it should be included in RewriteRule pattern. Side note -- there are no reasons to have 3 VirtualHosts **IF** those are the only directives they have and all of them are pointing to the same folder. You can get rid of first 2 VirtualHosts and add this line into 3rd instead: `ServerAlias website.com www.website.com`